# How to display the likes on a facebook page using Python on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, facebook, raspberry-pi

I have tried to get some code working to display the no of people who like a particular facebook page but cannot get any code examples to work i.e
https://graph.facebook.com/pdclews returns a dataset that does not include likes.

I want to achieve this on a raspberry pi using Python code if possible. Any help would be appreciated as this is a new area to me

Comment: You really should show some code to let people see how you have tried.

Comment: AFAIK by https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk you can access to all facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are an USER. You dont have likes on your page, using a group DOES work:

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/dumpertnl?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fnl-nl.facebook.com%2Fdumpertnl

Number of likes are in there :)

Comment: Dunno why this was voted down, the essential part of it is correct: User profiles don’t have “likes”, and OP queried the API for a user profile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the fields you want to access from the Page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?fields=likes
```

shows the number of likes of the cocacola page:

```
{
   "likes": 89560057,
   "id": "40796308305"
}
```